# How to retrieve values from dynamically created database in sqlite

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have created database without static name.Database created and tables are also created in that database,values are also inserted in that database,but when i am retrieving values from database by cursor, values are not returning from database.

Code for database helper class

```
  public class DatabaseClass extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;
/*  public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "FeetFork_Final_DataBase";*/
    public static final String TABLE_CAMPAIGN = "Campaign_Details";


    public SQLiteDatabase db;
   public DatabaseClass(Context context) {
        super(context, database_name, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        System.out.println("oncreateeeee");
        db.execSQL(Create_tables_campaign("Campaign"));
    }

    public String Create_tables_campaign(String a) {
        String CREATE_CAMPAIGN_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "
                + DatabaseClass.TABLE_CAMPAIGN + "(" + a
                + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY " + ")";
        return CREATE_CAMPAIGN_TABLE;
    }


    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CAMPAIGN);
        onCreate(db);
    }
```

code for fetching record...

```
Cursor c1 = db.query(DatabaseClass.TABLE_CAMPAIGN,columns_campaigns, null, null, null, null, null);
            c1.moveToFirst();
            while (!c1.isAfterLast()) {
                alist_campaign.add(c1.getString(0));
                c1.moveToNext();
            }
```

Comment: post columns_campaigns's values in question.

Comment: Please paste logcat if you are getting errors and also post the full code of your `DatabaseClass`.

Comment: private String[] columns_campaigns = { "Campaign" };
its a array which containing column name.

Comment: I am not getting any error .Getting null values and i checked cursor also its not null.

Comment: Then what does this mean: `...but when i am retrieving values from database by cursor, values are not returning from database.`

Comment: Please avoid pasting code in comments. Update your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
Cursor c1 = db.query(DatabaseClass.TABLE_CAMPAIGN,columns_campaigns, null, null, null, null, null);
                c1.moveToFirst();
                while (!c1.isAfterLast()) 
               {
                    alist_campaign.add(c1.getString(c1.getColumnIndex("Your_Column_Name")));
                    c1.moveToNext();
                }
```

Comment: You should give column name statically. so you can find value easily from database.

Comment: are u getting values from db properly or not?

Comment: if i am giving column name statically then also getting null. while loop is not working .

Comment: please check your cursor value by `int count = c1.getcount();` is it positive?

Comment: its giving 0 but this table have 1 value.

Comment: then your query is not correct. please review it. or check it by using adding more data in your table.

Comment: if i am using getcolumn count then its giving 1 and its right . but dont know why its not returning number of rows.

Comment: it is returning 1 because you have one column in your table. cursor.getcount() is return the value of rows in your cursor.

Comment: one value is also in column.

Answer (score 0):

try to check database version, If its same no change else your database its change.

Comment: I am doing database first time ,i don't know what is database version in sqlite. pLease explain me about this.

Comment: You define version when you first create database. its not created automatically

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Cursor c1 = db.query(DatabaseClass.TABLE_CAMPAIGN,columns_campaigns, null, null, null, null, null);
while (c1.moveToNext) {
   alist_campaign.add(c1.getString(0));
}
c1.close();
```

**Edit:**

Check whether Cursor is getting values or not, by logging:

```
Log.i("cursor length", c1.getCount()+"");
```